# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS repeated crashing - /var/crash/_usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.1000.crash

Tags: 18.04

My desktop is running on "Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, bionic".

I've recently run into a situation that my machine will crash and immediately kick me back out to the login screen.  It seems to be happening about every 15 minutes.  I prefer to avoid having to reinstall the operating system.  After I log in after the crash, there is always 2 new files in the /var/crash directory named .lock and _usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.1000.crash.  Even if I clear out this /var/crash directory, the two files will be recreated on the next system crash.

Any have any solutions or recommendations?

Comment: Since this issue might be related to your graphics card could you please share what hardware you are experiencing this on and the graphics driver you are currently using? This might help others in finding a solution for your problem.

Comment: @cauon I have the graphics card shown a "MSI GeForce GTX 1050 DirectX 12 GTX 1050 2G OC 2GB 128-Bit GDDR5 PCI Express 3.0 x16 HDCP Ready ATX Video Card".